# Converting while loop to for loop causes infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops

I've been having converting a while loop to a for loop. The problem I am having is the while loop works as intended, but when compiled the for loop causes an infinite loop. Any help would be awesome!

```
int y1 = 1776;
int y2 = 2008;

while(y1 <= y2){
    ++ y1;
    if( (y1%400==0 || y1%100!=0) &&(y1%4==0))
        cout << y1 <<" "<< "Is a Leap Year" << " ";
}
cout <<"Now with a for loop" << endl;

for(y1 <= y2; ++ y1;)
{
    if( (y1%400==0 || y1%100!=0) &&(y1%4==0))
        cout << y1;
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80153d8.aspx

Comment: You try to say that the for loop should continue if ++y1. And because this Will Never be 0, your for loop will never Exit.

Comment: im interested how this question got such a negative score for not being that bad of a question....

Answer (score 3):

you are very close but:

```
for(y1 <= y2; ++ y1;)
                   ^
```

should be:

```
for(;y1 <= y2; ++ y1)
    ^
```

note that because you are skipping any initializing, ie the usual `int i = 0` then you should make sure that its the first placer that is empty, not the last since for loops are structured like:

```
for(initialize stuff here; boolean here; iterator here)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int y1 = 1776;
int y2 = 2008;

for(;y1 <= y2; ++y1)
{
    if( (y1%400==0 || y1%100!=0) &&(y1%4==0))
        cout << y1;

}
```

Since `y1` has already a value, you can leave the initialization of the `for` loop empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop isn't complete. It should look like:

```
for (int y1 = 0; y1 <= y2; y1++)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your initial `y1` condition. Creating a second, inner,  `y1` to replace the outer is a bad idea, and I would not be surprised if it's not what OP has in mind

Answer (score -1):

Please take the time to do a fast google search to see the right syntax for a `for` loop. Here it is : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/